# Append content with similar rel values

Tags: jquery

I think I am stuck with this. I want to append the content of source into its target container based on rel similarities.

```
<div class="targets">
<div class="target target-1" rel="1">container 1</div>
<div class="target target-2" rel="2">container 2</div>
<div class="target target-3" rel="3">container 3</div>
</div>

<div class="sources">
<div class="source source-1" rel="1">source 1 content to append to container 1</div>
<div class="source source-2" rel="2">source 2 content to append to container 2</div>
<div class="source source-3" rel="3">source 3 content to append to container 3</div>
</div>
```

So **source 1 content to append to container 1** should be appended to **container 1**

I tried:

```
var rel_attr = $(this).attr('rel');
$('.source-' + rel_attr).appendTo('.target-' + rel_attr);
```

but to no avail. I must have missed something.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What you have will work fine assuming `this` is a reference to a `.source` element (if it is, more code would be helpful!): http://jsfiddle.net/Nrg4R/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not work because $(this) does not point somewhere. Try this

```
jQuery('.sources .source').each( function () {

    var content = jQuery(this).html(); //or .text();
    var rel = jQuery(this).attr('rel');

    jQuery('.targets .target-'+rel).html(content); // or .text() again;
    jQuery(this).hide();
    //use jQuery(this).html(''); if you do not want to hide the div

} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9YkSs/

Comment: This works, but I also want to remove original source from displaying. Thanks

Comment: jQuery(this).hide(); will do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm. Jquery has proved to save lots of PHP logic with this. Thanks to all and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you:

```
$("div[class^='source-']").each(function() {
    var tmpRel = $(this).attr("rel");
    var divClass= "target-"+tmpRel;
    $("div[class='"+divClass+"']").append($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.source').each(function()
{
  $(this).appendTo($('.targets').find('div.target[rel='+$(this).attr('rel')+']'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove 'source' DIVs from 'sources' wrapper and place inside relevant 'target' DIVs, try this

```
$(".source ").each(function(){
    var rel_attr = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.source-' + rel_attr).appendTo('.target-' + rel_attr);
});
```